# Making routes with 2 params at the same time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, routes, parameters

I'm really stuck with this. I'm new to rails.

I want to make a double parameter route to filter photos by 2 attributes .
If I'm visualizing photos by category 1 and click on zone 1, it should show photos with category 1 and zone 1 at the same time.

**Example:
I want to see photos that have category attribute : 1 and zone attribute : 1 at the same time. 
I've done:**

#### Photos Controller

```
`def type
     @photos = Photo.by_category(params[:category_id]).paginate(:page => params[:page])
     render :index
end

def zone
    @photos = Photo.by_zone(params[:zone_id]).paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render :index
end

def search
    @photos = Photo.with_user_avatar.all
    @photos = @photos.where('category = ?', params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id]
    @photos = @photos.where('zone = ?', params[:zone_id]) if params[:zone_id]
    @photos = @photos.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end`
```

#### Routes.rb

`get 'spots/:category_id', to: "photos#type", as: :spots_category
  get 'spots/zonas/:zone_id', to: "photos#zone", as: :spots_zone
  get 'spots/:category_id/:zone_id', to: "photos#search", as: :spots_category_zone
  get 'spots/zonas/:zone_id/:category_id', to: "photos#search", as: :spots_zone_category`

#### In my view

```
`<section class="row semi_padding_top">
<aside id="sidemenu" class="large-3 columns">
        <a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" data-options="align:right" class="button dropdown"></i>   Quiero ver spots de...</a><br>
            <ul id="drop1" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown" data-options="align:right">
                <li><%= link_to "Baños", spots_zone_path(1) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Cocinas", spots_zone_path(2) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Cuartos de estar", spots_zone_path(3) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Dormitorios", spots_zone_path(4) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Exteriores", spots_zone_path(5) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Hostelería", spots_zone_path(6) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Infantil", spots_zone_path(7) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Oficinas", spots_zone_path(8) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Salones", spots_zone_path(9) %></li>
            </ul>
        <h5 class="bold uppercase lightgrey">Estilos 
            <span class="green"><%= (@zone ? "para #{@zone}": "") %></h5></span>
                <ul class="listnone bold lightgrey">
                    <li><%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_path(1, zone: @zone) %>
                    <span class="spot_count small right"><%= @photos.count %></span></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Clásico", spots_category_path(2) %>
                    <span class="spot_count small right"><%= @photos.count %></span></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Industrial & Loft", spots_category_path(3), zone: @zone %>
                    <span class="spot_count small right"><%= @photos.count %></span></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Minimalista", spots_category_path(4), zone: @zone %>
                    <span class="spot_count small right"><%= @photos.count %></span></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Rústico", spots_category_path(5) %>
                    <span class="spot_count small right"><%= @photos.count %></span></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Contemporáneo", spots_category_path(6) %>
                    <span class="spot_count small right"><%= @photos.count %></span></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Étnico", spots_category_path(7) %>
                    <span class="spot_count small right"><%= @photos.count %></span></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Art Deco", spots_category_path(8) %>
                    <span class="spot_count small right"><%= @photos.count %></span></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Ecléctico", spots_category_path(9) %>
                    <span class="spot_count small right"><%= @photos.count %></span></li>
                </ul>

</aside>
<%= render 'spotlist' %>
```

`

I don't know how to configure my view to show a double parameter.

I've tried with **<%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_path(1, zone: @zone) %>** , but didn't work.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails will match parameters in the order they are specified in your route. For example:

```
get 'spots/:category_id/:zone_id', to: "photos#search", as: :spots_category_zone

<%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_zone_path(1, 'Moderno') %>
```

...would output a link to `http://localhost:3000/spots/1/Moderno`. You can also specify them explicitly:

```
<%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_zone_path(category_id: 1, zone_id: 'Moderno') %>
```

Or you can give it parameters not specified in the route, in which case it will append them as normal `?get=` values.

```
get 'spots/:category_id/:zone_id', to: "photos#search", as: :spots_category_zone
<%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_zone_path(1, 'Moderno', foo: 'bar') %>
```

...would give you `http://localhost:3000/spots/1/Moderno?foo=bar`.

Specifying them explicitly is helpful if you want to list them out of order for some reason.

```
<%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_zone_path(zone_id: 'Moderno', foo: 'bar', category_id: 1) %>
```

...still gives you `http://localhost:3000/spots/1/Moderno?foo=bar`.

In your case, if `@zone == 'foo'`, then `<%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_path(1, zone: @zone) %>` returns `http://localhost:3000/spots/1?zone=foo`. You want to use `spots_category_zone_path` as demonstrated in my first example..

Comment: But the thing is I need dynamic routes, because if I'm visualizing photos with Category "Moderno" and want to see a Zone with category "Baños", route should know what Category I'm seeing to build its route right? Thats why I can't make them explicitly..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Are you having issues linking from one category to another from within a view?

Comment: Nope, but how to I tell the route (in the link in the view) to have a dynamic parameter which is the category Im seeing so it can do `'spots/:category_im_seeing/:zone_i_want_to_filter'`?

Comment: Isn't that what `spots_category_zone_path` does? `<%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_zone_path(1, 'Moderno') %>`? Or if you want to do it dynamically, something like `<%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_zone_path(1, @object.category) %>`? That gives you `spots/1/Moderno` or whatever `@object.category` is.

Comment: Yes, my question is about the link in the view. Let me try this !

Comment: It should be:

`<%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_zone_path(1, @photos.zone) %>` right? So that zone is dynamic according to the view you are.

But doesn't work! Gives me:

undefined method `zone' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Photo:0x007ff5534b79b8>

Comment: No. `@photos` is returned by your controller, it is the result of a query, methods like `zone` are not available on it. I'm having a hard time visualizing how this is supposed to work. Are your zone links different for each image? Different for each page? Where is the list coming from in the first place?

Comment: I have a menu bar with category dropdown. If you select "Moderno" as category, Photos with category "Moderno" will be shown.

In that index view, I have a sidebar with zone filters.

Since I'm seing Photos with Moderno Category, I want to click in a Zone filter and see Photos with Moderno Category and Zone filter (the one I've chosen) .

Thats why, routes have to be dynamic, and know where are you coming from (In this case, Moderno) so that they have Moderno + The new zone youve chosen in params.

Comment: So you want to link to `spot/:current_category/:filter_category`, and it needs to know the current category so it can create links relative to that?

Comment: Try `@photos.first.zone` or `@photos.first.category`. If you're storing them as strings, it will return those names. `<%= link_to "Moderno", spots_category_zone_path(1, @photos.first.zone) %>`

Comment: Im storing them as ids, integers. Photo belongs to a category (1.....10). Each category has a name . So category.name with id=1 would be "Moderno". Still the same?

Comment: its giving me an error :

Association named 'avatar' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

I have in my controller: 

 def search
  @photos = Photo.with_user_avatar.all

Comment: Yey! Fixed, I had "category" in Photos Controller instead of "category_id". Thanks a lot! Where are u from? I owe you a beer! Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help. I'm in Brooklyn, NY. Let me know if you're ever in town!

Comment: Cool! Ill let you know If I'm there! Got your username